# How to read bar code without having bar code reader/ scanner?

Tags: substitute-tool, technology

As we have seen that In the digital world of today, every service is taken by machinery. You all now that in shopping malls and in almost all the shops ,seller sells their products by scanning them through bar code. This bar code tells all information regarding to product like price, manufacturing and expiery date etc.Sometimes customer is unaware about its actual price and usually customer is overcharged.

**So as a customer , how can we know the actual price of any object through its bar code without having bar code Scanner?**

Comment: "Usually customer is overcharged." I think you need to go to stores that are more trustworthy!

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what a barcode is for.

Comment: The bar-code is not more than a series of numbers. Often those numbers are printed with the bars, but if not you could read them from the width of the bars but it is useless as you will not know what the numbers stand for. Smart phones often have an app that will do the reading for you, but you end up with the numbers rather than the information you want.

Comment: Check to see that the barcode price matches the marked price on the shelf. It happens that the person who adds the prices of the barcodes for the store's check-out makes mistakes. It's not that rare after specials, markdowns, and new stock items are added to inventory. Errors can be in your favour or in the store's favour.

Comment: Sure, learn to read binary, bring a nanometer ruler, and hack into the store database to get the item name to price tables. Or, ask a worker

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes, just give the item to the store clerk and ask for a 'price check' to verify the price. When you get the price quoted from the reading by the clerk, make a note and/or check it against the price on the shelf or on the label. No?

Comment: @Stan I like the `learn to read binary, bring a nanometer ruler, and hack into the store database` option more (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bar code is a unique identifier that identify an item. As a customer you cannot obtain informations about the price because that vary from vendor to vendor.

It's like if you have written on a document a list of books that you want to sell with their prices and each books is represented by its ISBN:

`ISBN->Price`

If you want to know the price of a book from the list of another person you cannot find that information in your document.

*So the customers should have access to the vendor system to know the price of that item based on its bar code*.

Comment: I agree: products do not have a "real" price. Two stores can sell the same item for different prices. That is legal and common. That's why "bargain hunting" exists!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Peto's](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/24354/peto) answer (he's correct by saying you can't).

---

> So as a customer , how can we know the actual price of any object through its bar code without having bar code Scanner?

- The price of an item is what's encoded in the store system. So the way to know an item price (if it's not written near the item) is to let the cashier scan it.

I assume that the price is written near the item, or with a sticker on it - if so, you can (and should, if you care about your money) compare the receipt to what you expected to pay.

**There are errors, it's inevitable** - it might be in the encoding process in the vendor system, or in the cashier typing (for products without a barcode on them, such as fruits for example).

Anyway, as a wise consumer, it's your responsibility to go over your receipt and check that your payment was correct - if not, go back to the cashier to fix that and get your money back.

---

And as for what [BrettFromLA](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/4198/brettfromla) said:

> "Usually customer is overcharged." I think you need to go to stores that are more trustworthy!

**Absolutely.**
Errors may (and will) occur, but not dramatically and certainly not *usually*.